# Is there anyway appium automatically registers connected device and run the automation

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium, selenium-grid

I am trying to perform automation on multiple devices using Selenium Grid and Appium. Everytime I run the tests I need to run the Hub and Register the node to the hub and then perform the automation.

Is there anyway we can run the Selenium Hub and Register node. If I start running the tests. I am using Maven at the moment.

Comment: what maven commands are you using to start running the tests? have you tried Jenkins or any build scheduler?

Comment: If you are using some CI tool like Jenkins, CircleCI, Bamboo etc. you can easily automate this. You just need to create a task or job that runs a batch file which launches your hub and another batch file which registers the node to the hub.
Then sequence this batch file execution job to run before every test suite execution. You would also need to add similar batch file execution job to stop the hub after the test suite execution.